# Find value that occurs in odd number of elements

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired.

For example, in array A such that:

```
A[0] = 9  A[1] = 3  A[2] = 9
A[3] = 3  A[4] = 9  A[5] = 7
A[6] = 9
```

the elements at indexes 0 and 2 have value 9,
the elements at indexes 1 and 3 have value 3,
the elements at indexes 4 and 6 have value 9,
the element at index 5 has value 7 and is unpaired.
Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array A consisting of N integers fulfilling the above conditions, returns the value of the unpaired element.

This is my attempt. It passes the test cases, however any feedback on improving it will be great:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    if (A == null || A.Length <= 0) return 0;

    Dictionary<int, int> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach(int number in A) {
    // using the index of count same way you'd use a key in a dictionary
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(number))
        dictionary[number] ++;

    else dictionary.Add(number, 1);
    }

    foreach(var item in dictionary)
    {
        if(item.Value == 0) return item.Key;

        else if(item.Value %2 != 0) return item.Key;
    }   

    return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the right place for working code that you want to have critiqued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this. Just for fun I tried a few. It might help you to see some of the different approaches.

**Using LINQ**

This sort of thing is exactly what [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) was built for. Unless there is a performance issue, this is probably the way most professional developers would do it, because it is intuitive (if you know LINQ). Here is solution in one line:

```
//using System.Linq;

public static int UseLinq(int[] input)
{
    return input
        .GroupBy( n => n )
        .Where( g => g.Count() %2 == 1)
        .Select( g => g.Key )
        .Single();
}
```

**The way you did it**

Using a dictionary to keep track of counts, similar to your approach.

```
public static int WithDictionary(int[] input)
{
    var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    foreach (int n in input)
    {
        if (!counts.ContainsKey(n))
        {
            counts[n]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            counts[n]++;
        }
    }
    foreach (var d in counts)
    {
        if (d.Value % 2 == 1) return d.Key;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**The way you did it, but generating the dictionary using LINQ**

```
public static int WithDictionaryAndLinq(int[] input)
{
    var counts = input.GroupBy( n => n )
                      .ToDictionary( g => g.Key, g=> g.Count() );

    foreach (var d in counts)
    {
        if (d.Value % 2 == 1) return d.Key;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**With pair tracking**

Sort of like the way you did it, but instead of keeping a count, just keep track of which items haven't been paired yet. This seems like the shortest solution.

```
public static int WithPairTracking(int[] input)
{
    var odd = new List<int>();
    foreach (var n in input)
    {
        if (odd.Contains(n)) odd.Remove(n); 
        else odd.Add(n);
    }
    return odd[0];
}
```

**Sorting the array first**

If the runtime provides a fast `Sort()` algorithm (like .NET does), this may be the solution that has the best performance, as you only have to iterate over the array a single time.

```
public static int UseSort(int[] input)
{
    Array.Sort(input);
    if (input[0] != input[1]) return input[0];
    for ( int i = 1; i < input.GetUpperBound(0); i++ )
    {
        if (input[i] == input[i+1]) continue;
        if (input[i] == input[i-1]) continue;
        return input[i];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Parallel**

Here's a multithreaded solution. Not really recommended due to the problem of [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing); might not perform any better than single-threaded.

```
public static int WithParallelLoop(int[] input)
{
    int result = -1;

    Parallel.ForEach
    ( 
        input, 
        (element,state) =>
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var n in input)
            {
                if (n == element) found = !found;
            }
            if (found) 
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref result, element);
                state.Stop();
            }
        }
    );
    return result;
}
```

**List removal**

This solution puts the array in a list and removes them pairwise until only one element remains.

```
public static int ByRemovingFromList(int[] input)
{
    var list = input.ToList();
    while (list.Count != 0)
    {
        var n = list[0];
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        var i = list.IndexOf(n);
        if (i == -1) return n;
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**By removing from an array** (my favorite of all these)

Like the "list removal" solution above, but trying for efficiency by sticking with arrays and reducing the search space instead of removing and reallocating a list. This solution will probably have the best performance overall because it requires no memory allocation and items already found are excluded from further searches via a shrinking window (by increasing `i`).

```
public static int ByRemovingFromArray(int[] input)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i <= input.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
        var n = input[i];
        var j = Array.IndexOf(input, n, ++i);
        if (j == -1) return n;
        input[j] = input[i++];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Brute force**

For completeness' sake.

```
public static int BruteForce(int[] input)
{
    for (int i=0; i<=input.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        int matchCount = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<=input.GetUpperBound(0); j++)
        {
            if (i == j) continue;
            if (input[i] == input[j])
            {
                matchCount++;
            }
        }
        if (matchCount % 2 == 0) return input[i];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

[Here's my code on DotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eLIZ1K)

Comment: With `10000` pairs and `random.Next(0,1000)` values... `ByRemovingFromList` is slowest, followed by `WithPairTracking`, `WithParallelLoop` and `ByRemovingFromArray` in order. Everything else (except brute force) is fastest and similar in speed, including if you fix `WithPairTracking` using a hash set. (N.B. I had to fix `UseSort`.)

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine was, nice job.

Answer (score 2):

One more way is using XOR bitwise operation. In which every same number will cancel out each other and only unique value will be left.

Here is the code:

```
def solution(A):
    uniq_elem = 0
    for elm in A:
        uniq_elem = elm ^ uniq_elem
    return uniq_elem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the soltuion of [Codility - Odd Occurrences In Array Problem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array/) then, here is the **JavaScript** code which gave 100% for me.

```
function solution(A) {
    let result = 0;
    A.forEach(i=>result ^= i);
    return result
}
```

Ref : [Find the odd occurrences in an array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128608/255759)

Answer (score 0):

In JS,

```
function solution(arr) {
  if(arr.length == 0) return 0;
  if(arr !== undefined && arr !== null){
      let obj = {}
      for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
          obj[arr[i]] ?  obj[arr[i]]++ :obj[arr[i]]= 1;
      }

      for(let key in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          if(obj[key] == 1)
            return Number(key);
        }
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```